# Java - HttpURLConnection PUT request with empty body

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection, put

I'm trying make a request with Java, when I call it using cURL like this, it works:

```
curl -X PUT http://serverurl.com/method/6eb276a2-5c79-4f6e-a4b5-a26b0e6848c7/action  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Token: cba5f12c-af55-480f-970e-525e446ef153' -H 'Content-Length : 0'
```

If I call the same request without passing header Content-Length param, I get 411 HTTP error, length required.

This is my code in Java:

```
URL url = new URL("http://serverurl.com/method/6eb276a2-5c79-4f6e-a4b5-a26b0e6848c7/action");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.addRequestProperty("Token", "cba5f12c-af55-480f-970e-525e446ef153");
con.connect();
```

This request is getting a 411 HTTP code response. So, I tryed to add:

```
con.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
```

But it doesn't work, so I changed to:

```
URL url = new URL("http://serverurl.com/method/6eb276a2-5c79-4f6e-a4b5-a26b0e6848c7/action");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.addRequestProperty("Token", "cba5f12c-af55-480f-970e-525e446ef153");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.getOutputStream().close();
con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(0);
con.connect();
```

But now I'm getting 400 HTTP code.

How can I do a PUT request with an empty body and setting content length to match the cURL call?

Answer (score 0):

using the HttpUrlConnection, you should use the setRequestProperty method to add headers to your request. I can see your using the "addRequestProperty" which is probably why its not working. But refer to this link for more info https://juffalow.com/java/how-to-send-http-get-post-request-in-java  and heres some code that i use to for a put request

```
        URL url = new URL(BASE_URL+"/"+userID+".json");
        urlRequest = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlRequest.setDoOutput(true);
        urlRequest.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        urlRequest.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; 
        charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStream os = urlRequest.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

        osw.write("{\"idToken\":\""+"token"+"\"}");


        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        urlRequest.connect();
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) 
        urlRequest.getContent()));//Convert the input stream to a json element

        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();//Maybe an array or object
```

well thats just sample what i use... and i hope this works for you. Happy coding.